# method to download mp3 file from url

Tags: iphone

If someone want to download a file instead of playing it, then what functionality or method will be used for it.

I want to download the file. Provide me some example if u can, or give me some idea about this concept.

Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 1):

Send request following way.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[fileUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[theRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bytes=%ld-",0] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Range"];
[theRequest addValue: @"pdf" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
webData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

Implement following methods...

`-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response`

`-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}`

`-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection )connection
{

    /******CODE FOR WRITING FILE*************/ 
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);`

```
NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *directoryPath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[MAIN_DIRECTORY stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileDate]];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:directoryPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];

[webData writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
```

}